# Getting "Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'PRIMARY'" While using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

Right off the bat I want to say, due to my position I cannot paste the full code. So I will do what I can to symbolize the code and get straight to the point.

**Programmed in: Python**.

Simply put I am getting a Duplicate Key Error. I have looked into other questions that have been raised about this and to my knowledge I am following the suggestion those answers have provided.

Table Structure Snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE `BAR_TABLE` (
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`foo` tinytext,
`bar` tinytext,
`uuid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

In this case 'uuid' is the PRIMARY as there already a dataset this is taking in, that uuid is always unique(Unless it already exists then it's updating potential info)

SQL Snippet

```
INSERT INTO BAR_TABLE (
    foo, 
    bar,
    uuid  
    ) VALUES (
        %(foo)s, 
        %(bar)s, 
        %(uuid)s
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        foo = VALUES(foo), 
        bar = VALUES(bar)
```

So the reason the SQL looks like this is because I am using executemany(). As well as the data that comes in is a Python Dictionary. So this allows it to assign all the values in the dictionary data to the SQL statement. Then all that gets shifted into the DB using executemany().

The item it is throwing the duplicate entry is actually in the table. I managed to get this to run a couple times, and then at some point during its testing it hit this error, and hasn't moved past it.

Obviously I am miss understanding something. Am I miss-understanding how the PRIMARY KEY works? Or what a KEY is using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: Do you have any triggers? The error could be coming from there.

Comment: @Barmar I do have triggers, 3. On Insert, on Update, On Delete. 
On insert add a "Added entry" into a history table. On Update Add an "Updated Entry" where is insert the old and new values for that row. On Delete, add an "Deleted Entry" preserving the item to archive.

I will disable the triggers to see if it still has issues.

Comment: Is it a before-insert or after-insert trigger? A before-insert trigger will run whether it's a duplicate key or not. If it's a duplicate, an after-update trigger runs; it it's not a duplicate an after-insert trigger will run.

Comment: Turns out it was the Trigger that INSERT an item to the Deleted table, and  that is an After trigger.